# How to do something when an inputbox is focused in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a searchbox with the ID "searchbox" - and I am trying to show and hide an element called "feed" based on whether or not the user has the searchbox focused.

```
<script>
document.getElementById("searchbox").addEventListener("focus", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("feed").style.display= "none";
}
</script>
```

The function above isn't functioning correctly (feed isn't disappearing) - so it would be great if I could get some guidance on how to better structure the function

Comment: [Works for me.](https://jsfiddle.net/h4e7vw0j/)  Can you provide a complete example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Did you mean to use "focusin" and "focusout"? Or maybe "focus" and "blur" to toggle the display?

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML and indicate where within the HTML document your script is located. Do you get any errors in the developer's console (F11)? Do you have your `script` located just before the closing `body` tag?

Answer (score 0):

To toggle `feed` you'll need to handle the `blur` event in addition to `focus`.

Here's a working example. Make sure that your `script` tag comes after your DOM elements:

```html
<html>
  <input id="searchbox" type="input" />
  <div id="feed">feed</div>
  <script>
    const searchbox = document.getElementById("searchbox");
    const feed = document.getElementById("feed");
    searchbox.addEventListener("focus", () => feed.style.display = "none");
    searchbox.addEventListener("blur", () => feed.style.display = "block");
  </script>
</html>
```